# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character(probably duplicate, but I need a help)

Tags: python-3.x, encode

I have tried to read plain text with python3 after I downloaded a file (g_doc.txt in following code) from google documents. Then, It produce error somehow.

```
# $file --mime g_doc.txt >> g_doc.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8  
txt = open("g_doc.txt", encoding = "utf-8") 

print(txt.read())
>>UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character....in range(128)
```

It seems that there are lots of question and answer for this kinds of error. Then, I searched and tried these method. But, My code did not work well in the end. Do you guys have any solution in python3 for simple example?

I did not change default encoding. It is still ascii.

Comment: Where are you running the code from? Also post the full traceback

Comment: I am currently running this code on Atom.

Comment: Full trace back is : File "/Users/kojisugano/Documents/sample.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(txt.read())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Where are you running it from?

Comment: you are asking about my laptop environment? that is OSX 10.10.5.